# Running external Javascript in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

new to this stuff, please bear with me.
I have an external js file, declared in my HTML etc. JS code is fine and works in Fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/0hu4fs4y/

```
<script src="js/noti.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.flexslider-min.js"></script>
<script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
```

However, it doesn't work. Am I running an old JQuery Library?

Is it something stupid/obvious I'm missing?

Comment: I feel your files, `noti.js` and `scripts.js` depend on jQuery, so include `jquery.min.js` as the first file and the rest of them later on. Alternatively try using `jQuery.noConflict()` too.  https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/

Comment: You may want to check the console (F12 on modern browsers) to check if there is an error message.

Comment: Your fiddle only has one js file.  Which is it?  Don't hide code behind a fiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things:

1. I'm guessing `noti.js` relies on jQuery. If so, it should be **after** the script tag that includes jQuery (probably down with your `scripts.js`).
2. Make sure these script tags are at the **end** of the HTML, just before the closing `</body>` element, so that the elements they act on exist when the scripts run.

Your code works in the fiddle because you've pasted the code directly in and used jsFiddle's (mind-numbingly surprising) default that waits to run your code until the `window` `load` event runs, which is very, very late in the page load process. If you're a beginner, you've probably seen the anti-pattern of putting `script` tags in `head` and done that in your stuff, meaning that your elements don't exist when your code runs, because the parser hasn't seen them yet.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer T.J - Like magic, moving the script tags to the bottom worked. Great, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

the console error at jsfiddle is:

> ReferenceError: $ is not defined

which could be becasue your `noti.js` is using `jquery` 
put jquery script on top of all other `script`